# HTTP call after celery task have changed state

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I need a scheduler for my next project, and since I'm coding using Django I went for [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

What I am looking for is a way for a task to tell Django when it is done, so I can update the database and use [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) to tell the user. All this can be done fairly simple with just putting all the logic into the task. But what do I do when I am planning to have several celery workers?

I found a bunch of info online to cover the single-worker-case, but not many covering the problem if you have more than one worker.

What I thought about was using http callbacks from the workers to the web-server to let it know that the task is done. Looking at [celery.task.http](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.task.http.html) looked promising, but didnt do what I needed.

Is the solution to use [signals](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html) and hook up manual http calls? Or am I on the wrong path? Isn't this a common problem? How can this be solved more elegantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that seems to do what I want:

In django settings:

```
CELERY_ANNOTATIONS = {
    "*": {
        "on_failure": celery_handlers.on_failure,
        "on_success": celery_handlers.on_success
    }
}
```

In the celery_handlers.py file included:

```
def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, *args, **kwargs):
    # Use urllib or similar to poke eg; api-int.mysite.com/task_handler/TASK_ID
    pass

def on_success(self, retval, task_id, *args, **kwargs):
    # Use urllib or similar to poke eg; api-int.mysite.com/task_handler/TASK_ID
    pass
```

And then you can just setup api-int to use something like:

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
task_obj = AsyncResult(task_id)
# Logic to handle task_obj.result and related goes here....
```

Answer (score 1):

So, what are you mean when you tell tell to Django? Is I understand you right, django request which initiliazed a Celery task, is still alive a time when this task is finished? I that case you can check some storage ( database, memcached, etc ). and send your SSE.
Look, there is one way to do that.
1. You django view send task to Celery, after that it goes to infinite loop ( or loop with timeout 60sec?) and waits results in memcached.

1. Celery gets task executes, and pastes results to memcached.
2. Django view gets new results, exit the loop and sends your SSE.

Next variant is

1. Django view sends task to Celery, and returns
2. Celery execute tasks, after executing it makes simple HTTP  requests to your django app.
3. Django receives a http request from Celery, parse params and send SSE to your user again

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The steps you are describing under "Next variant is", is exactly what I'm doing and have described, and what I think is the best solution.. I am writing down some code in an answer that looks like does the trick.